# Moment js timezone off by 1 hour

Tags: momentjs

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Passing in a string to `moment`, with the format and calling .toDate().

toDate() ends up returning a time that is off by 1 hour

```
moment("2015-11-19T18:34:00-07:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ").toDate()
 > Thu Nov 19 2015 17:34:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

The time should be `18:34`, not `17:34`. The timezone is showing `-08`, when it should be showing `-07`

Comment: Daylight saving time.

Comment: Ah, this crosses a DST boundary... Sunday, November 1